# Multiple App Support Using APN on Rails Gem

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have a couple iPhone apps talking to one ruby on rails server. I have been using the apn_on_rails gem by mark bates/PRX (http://github.com/PRX/apn_on_rails) to offer push notifications to both apps.

The README specifies how to support one app, but I need to support two apps. Not only that, but I would like to send out these notifications in batches using the included rake task, as recommended in the README.

Any help would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The new gem by prx now supports multiple apps.

https://github.com/PRX/apn_on_rails